# Replace Yes with 1 and No with 0

Tags: sas-analytics

I have a data set and an example of the field is below. The values of these fields is "Yes" or "No". I would like to replace the value of "Yes" with 1 and the value of "No" with 0.

This file will be exported from Sharepoint each month and at the moment it is 50,000 rows and will increase each month. I have 48 fields which I would like to do the replace of "Yes" and "No".

#### Example of the field

```
t1.'Domestic Violence'n,
```

I'm using the below to accomplish what I'd like, but was hoping there is a better way to do this. Ideally, I don't want to create another column.

I am using [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_(software)). For example:

```
 t1.'Domestic Violence'n as DomesticViolence, 
      case when(DomesticViolence='Yes') then 1
        else 0
        end as Domestic_Violence,
```

I would like a more efficient way (less coding). With the above I'll have a column called 'DomesticViolence' (values of "Yes" and "No") and  a column called 'Domestic_Violence'. Ideally I'd only want the column called 'Domestic_Violence'.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to return both `Yes`/`No`s and `1`/`0`s, then exclude columns like

```
t1.'Domestic Violence' as DomesticViolence
```

from your query and have your CASE expression reference the source columns rather than their aliases:

```
case
  when (t1.'Domestic Violence' = 'Yes') then 1
  else 0
end as Domestic_Violence
```